# Portable USB Webserver

Tags: webserver, portable-applications

I have project that I'm working on that is going to require a webserver.  The webserver will be used to remotely control a presentation using a mobile device.

I see there are quite a few options out there and I'm wondering if someone could provide some recommendations.

My criteria include:

- Portable, fits on a USB key
- Easy to
  run.  A user can just click on an
  icon, or ideally it would include an
  autorun command.
- Open Source.  I would prefer something licensed under the GPL or similar.
- Runs a dynamic server-side language.  I see that most have PHP which works perfectly, but I'm open to other languages.
- Cross platform if possible.

Right now I'm leaning towards XAMPP, but I would love to hear some suggestions.

Comment: Maybe you can try [USBWebserver (~22MB)](http://www.usbwebserver.net/en/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) is perfect for this.

Comment: I can't get XAMPP to work. Any suggestions here? I've tried the USB Lite, Zip and EXE...

Comment: thanks for the comment. I install it onto the usb stick, then try and start the server with no luck. The lite did start one time, then I couldn't install Drupal for some odd reason. The Lite version doesn't include the Control panel. Are you using the full version on a usb drive?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html), so I think you are on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Have not used this, but it looks like it would be right up your alley:

http://www.blackdot.be/?inc=apache/httpserveronusb

Supports perl + php by default.

From the page:
If you are a web developer I'm sure you have had that moment where you went:
"If only I had a web server handy right now!"

Then HTTP Server On USB is something for you! HTTP Server On USB is a fully configured web server that runs from your USB-Key. Plug it in and off you go!
It can be use to show of a website to a costumer, share files with your friends (both ways thanks to DAV) or simply impress people but acting all geeky!

Are you special and do you depend on exotic 3rd party module?
Just drop them in the module folder and edit the configuration file!

Features:

- Management Application
- Apache 2.2.11

  - mod_deflate
  - mod_ssl
- mod_security
- mod_perl
- PHP 5.2.8
- ActiveState Perl 5.10

Requirements:

- Windows 2000, Windows XP or Windows 2003
- 256mb USB-key

Answer (score 1):

I have had no luck with XAMPP Lite or USBWebserver. What is currently working really well is [Server2Go](http://server2go-web.de). I could never get XAMPP to run and USBWebserver would not allow me to install Drupal or Wordpress.

With Server2Go, I was able to install Drupal 7 on the USB Flash Drive, however, only with SQLite. I did need to go to the php folder and copy and rename the production-php.ini file to php.ini. There is a php.ini setting that needs to be set for the MySQL DB to be recognized. It is running well with SQLite for Development purposes though.

Answer (score 0):

[LAMPPIX](http://lamppix.tinowagner.com/) - looks like not up to date, but should do the job.

Answer (score -4):

I would suggest Apache, pretty lightweight and has everything you'll need (PHP).